# Object Type Converter for varying argued types

Tags: vb.net, list, dictionary, casting, return-type

Say I have two dictionaries:

```
Dim dict1 as new dictionary(Of Integer, String)
Dim dict2 as new dictioanry(Of customType, customtype2)
```

I want to convert them to a list in a method and return a list of the argued dictionary value type. So....

```
Public Function DictToListConverter(ByVal argDict as Dictionary(Of Object, Object), ByVal argType as Type) **What goes here.
```

I know I can just cast the return on the calling routine, but that is not the best solution. I would not like to return a custom class which contains the values.In other words I'm looking for a way to do the following:

Pass in dictionary(Of Integer, **String**) and get a return of List(Of **String**)

at the same time, if I pass in a dictionary (of String, **Boolean**) then the function should return List(of **Boolean**)

It is looking like this is not possible and I either have to use class / struct, or just cast the object in the calling routine. Just wanted to get a verification on whether or not this request is possible.

Again, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using .Net 3.5 or later you can do that with the following...

```
Public Function DictToListConverter(Of TKey, T)(dict As Dictionary(Of TKey, T)) As List(Of T)
    Return dict.Select(Function(i As KeyValuePair(Of TKey, T)) i.Value).ToList()
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `List(Of Object)`, or `ArrayList`, which is more or less the same.